# Autocomplete extender not working inside modal popup extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am opening a popup in which I have a textbox. I want to use Ajax autocomplete extebder for this textbox. But it's not able to call the webservice method for autocompletion. Can't understand weather it's a problem of postback or updatepanel.

Where I should use the update panel? My page containing popup div is already inside "updatepanel1".

Code snap is given below. Help Me...

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"   ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditMPName" runat="server" Width="408px" AutoPostBack="true"        BackColor="#CCFFFF" OnTextChanged="txtEditMPName_TextChanged">
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ace2" runat="server" BehaviorID="autoSuggest" 
  DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetParty" CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="true"   CompletionSetCount="1" OnClientShown="ShowOptions"
  TargetControlID="txtEditMPName" FirstRowSelected="True" CompletionListCssClass="AutoCompleteCompletionList" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoCompleteCompletionListHighlightedItem" CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoCompleteCompletionListItem">
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtEditMPName" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: u can use , jquery for tht... bcos autocompleteextender gives problme for tht

Comment: You are not specifying the `ServicePath` property. Is `GetParty()` a page method?

Comment: i have written the web method in the page itself.thats why no service path property

Comment: bcastillo solution works! Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24480138/12815475

Answer (score 2):

You can just add *Z-INDEX* on CSS classes for the 3 parts of autocomplete-extender

************************ Autocomplete extender control ***********************************

CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"                                    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"

*************************** CSS *************************************

```
    /* AutoComplete highlighted item */
    .autocomplete_completionListElement
    {
        margin: 0px !important;
        z-index:99999 !important;
        background-color: ivory;
        color: windowtext;
        border: buttonshadow;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        cursor: 'default';
        overflow: auto;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: left;
        left: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    /* AutoComplete highlighted item */
    .autocomplete_highlightedListItem
    {
        z-index:99999 !important;
        background-color: #ffff99;
        color: black;
        padding: 1px;
        cursor:hand;
    }
    /* AutoComplete item */
    .autocomplete_listItem
    {
        z-index:99999 !important;
        background-color: window;
        color: windowtext;
        padding: 1px;
        cursor:hand;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

create a JavaScript function.

```
function PopupShown(sender, args) {
        sender._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 99999999;
    }
```

and use the property in "AutoCompleteExtender"

```
OnClientShown="PopupShown"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier:

1. Create inside the modalpopup another div: <div ID="ListDivisor">
2. Set this property in your autocomplete extender: CompletionListElementID="ListDivisor"